# Get absolute path of caller file

Tags: python

Say I have two files in different directories: `1.py` (say, in `C:/FIRST_FOLDER/1.py`) and `2.py` (say, in `C:/SECOND_FOLDER/2.py`).

The file `1.py` imports `2.py` (using `sys.path.insert(0, #path_of_2.py)` followed, obviously, by `import 2`) and calls one of the functions in `2.py`, the function it calls needs to know the absolute path of `1.py` (it looks for a file in that same directory).

I know there's `inspect.stack()[1]` but this only returns the file name and not the path.

Any idea on how to implement this?

Comment: Maybe you should reorganize your code and improve your logic so it does not expect the file to read in the same directory.

Comment: Note that you cannot `import` Python files that have a name like `2.y` because `2` is not a valid identifier so an `import 2` will result in a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To return the absolute path of a python file, use python's `__file__` attribute:

```
import os
path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

Comment: It actually works! I did know of `abspath()` but had no idea it would work in this case, I wonder how that function works, assuming there is more than one file with the same name in the operating system.

Comment: @Jonathan: This does not give you the absolute path of the *caller* file.

Answer (score 10):

```
import inspect
import os

abs_path = os.path.abspath((inspect.stack()[0])[1])
directory_of_1py = os.path.dirname(abs_path)
```

for more information on the module [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html)

Comment: At least in Python 3.8.5 inspect.stack()[0][1] gives the path to the file where the function is; inspect.stack()[1][1] gives the path to the caller file